# Passing variable from controller to view - Laravel

Tags: php, variables, laravel, view, controllers

I'm trying to pass a variable from one view to a controller to another view. I'm not getting any errors, but when it gets to the last view, it doesn't show the variable like it's supposed to. In the first view, I'm just getting a name.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'form', 'method'=>'post')) }}
    {{ $name = Form::text('name') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Go!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here is my HomeController.php.

```
public function view1()
{
    return View::make('stuff');
}

public function postView1($name)
{
    return Redirect::route('view2')->with($name);
}

public function view2($name)
{
    return View::make('view2')->with($name);
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'stuff', 'uses' => 'HomeController@stuff'));
Route::post('form/{name}', array('as' => 'form', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postView1'));
Route::get('view2/{name}', array('as' => 'view2', 'uses' => 'HomeController@view2'));
```

view2.blade.php

```
{{ $name = Input::get('name') }}
<p> Hello, {{ $name }} </p>
```

So why isn't it showing up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you should change your `postView` function into:

```
public function postView1()
{
    return Redirect::route('view2', ['name' => Input::get('name')]);
}
```

And your route:

```
Route::post('form/{name}', array('as' => 'form', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postView1'));
```

into:

```
Route::post('form', array('as' => 'form', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postView1'));
```

Now, you should change your `view2` function into:

```
public function view2($name)
{
    return View::make('view2')->with('name',$name);
}
```

Now in your `view2.blade.php` you should be able to use:

```
<p> Hello, {{ $name }} </p>
```

Comment: That makes sense now. But I'm still having a problem. Now, when it gets to view2, it just says "Hello, {name}" instead of actually showing the name.

Comment: @porcupine92 And what exactly URL you put into browser for that? You should use for example `http://localhost/yourproject/view2/porcupine92`

Comment: When I type a name into the text field for the form and click the submit button, it goes to view2 and just says "Hello, {name}". The URL just says `http://localhost/myproject/view2/%7Bname%7D`. If I type `http://localhost/yourproject/view2/porcupine92` for the URL, it just says "Hello, " with no name at all.

Comment: @porcupine92 I've edited my answer, now data is injected as route parameter

Comment: I'm getting a "NotFoundHttpException" now. Could that be because of a problem with my routes?

Comment: @porcupine92 And what url you use now when you get this exception? You should be precise and make sure code is exactly the same as I showed.

Comment: My code looks exactly like yours. When I use the url `http://localhost/myproject/view2/porcupine92`, it does say "Hello, porcupine92". But why won't it do that when I use the submit button? Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. Hopefully someday I'll be as good as you with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the variable:

```
public function view2($name)
{
    return View::make('view2')->with('name', $name);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it still didn't work. Do you have any other ideas about what could be wrong with what I'm doing? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array (
            'title'=>'My App yo',
            'Description'=>'This is New Application',
            'author'=>'foo'
        );
        return view('home')->with($data);;
    }
}
```

Comment: view page                
<?php 
echo $title;
?>

Comment: Good answer. This is one of the cleanest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try form will be if you using POST method why setting variable in route it will get directly on your function with post data.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'form', 'method'=>'post')) }}
    {{Form::text('name') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Go!') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

route :-

```
Route::post('form','HomeController@postView1');
```

controller function :-

```
public function postView1() {
  $data = Input::all();
  return Redirect::route('view2')->with('name', $data['name']);
}
```

and get data on view2 :-

```
<p> Hello, {{ $name }} </p>
```

For more follow [HERE](http://www.tutsnare.com/pass-data-from-controller-to-view-laravel/)

Comment: I did that, and it gave me the error - "Undefined index: name". How would I fix that?

Comment: check print_r($data); you have name exist in your post data? also check updated form

Answer (score -1):

Here's what other answers are missing, straight from [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects):

> Since the **with** method flashes data to the session, you may retrieve the data using the typical **Session::get** method.

So instead of `{{$name}}` write `{{Session::get('name')}}`.