# Laravel 5 and MS SQL server connection error

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, sql-server-2012

new to laravel framework, I am running multiple database connections for a project I am working on. Just a simple test against one of the mysql instance,

```
<p>{{ $data2 = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('test')->get() }}</p>
```

gives a simple dump but when run simmilar test against the ms sql server 2012, it errors out

```
<p>{{ $data3 = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('test1')->get() }}</p>
```

The error is:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 519:
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() must return a string value
```

my db config is similar to other examples I have seen posted online.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'SQL3.company.ca'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '#######'),
          'collation' =>  'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
          'charset'   =>  'latin1',
        'prefix' => '',
],
```

Did I set up something wrong? any direction I should be looking at?

Comment: your query returns an array and laravel looks for a string..

Comment: you should run queries in your controller and return the results along with the view. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26354972/4668162

Comment: `{{dd(DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('test1')->get()) }} `not goodif get data logic in view u should write model or controller

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I did manage a return with 
`p>{{ $data4 = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('test1')->select(DB::RAW('username'))->get() }}</p>` to the sql 2012 server, and I started testing/working on connection to the old sql 2005 server. Returned this morning, and the successful connection wasn't working anymore and getting the 'SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)' so something I did last night or servers changed last night.. so much fun