# Automatically select value in the options with the url parameters I am coming from

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, hello, and forgive me in a slightly worse English language

index.blade.php

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="toolbar-tools pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                    @if(Entrust::can('add_post'))
                        <li>
                            @foreach($main_title_options as $option)
                                <a href="{{ url('admin/post/create') }}" @if(isset($_GET['main_title']) && $_GET['main_title'] == $option->value)>

                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    {{ trans('labels.create_' . $option->value   ) }}
                                    @else
                                        {{ trans('labels.create_posts') }}
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach

                                </a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

main_title.blade.php

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="main_title">{{ trans('labels.main_title') }}</label>
                    <select v-model="post.main_title | mainTitle" name="main_title"
                            id="main_title"
                            class="form-control">
                        @foreach($main_title_options as $option)
                            <option {{ old('main_title') == $option->value ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $option->value }}">
                                {{ trans('labels.'.$option->value) }}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

I want to, for example, if I come with http://nesto.test/admin/post?main_title=post, automatically select value is 'post', and if I come with http://nesto.test/admin/post?main_title=manifestacion , automatically select value will be 'manifestation'

I hope you understand what I want, thank you in advance

Comment: GET the variable in the routes file and then pass it in the view to use it as a variable in your blade file.

Comment: In your index.blade.php you are adding if(isset inside <a> before the tag is complete ">" else inside a tag. endforeach should be after </a>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use controller then this is a sample controller function in which we accept get variable in $request and pass it to view file

```
public function my_function(Request $request)
{
    //Put main_title in a variable
    $main_title = $request->main_title;

    //Pass main_title to view
    return view('yourview', compact('main_title'));
}
```

Or you can directly send get parameter to view from your route file

```
Route::get('/admin/post',function(Request $request)
{
    $main_title = $request->main_title;
    return view('yourview', compact('main_title'));
});
```

include Request ad the beginning of the file

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Now you can access $main_title variable in view file like

```
<option {{ $main_title == $option->value ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $option->value }}">
```

If you want more info refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353030/passing-variable-from-controller-to-view-laravel)

Comment: why create a controller when you can directly send it to the view?

Comment: Yes you can but this is just a suggestion as you have not mentioned anything related to controller or route.

Comment: It did not work, but thanks for the effort, i updated quastion